# Proper use of the HsOpenSSL API to implement a TLS Server

Tags: haskell, openssl, ssl

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use the [OpenSSL.Session](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HsOpenSSL/0.10.3.1/doc/html/OpenSSL-Session.html) API in a concurrent context

E.g. assume I want to implement a `stunnel-style ssl-wrapper`, I'd expect to have the following basic skeleton structure, which implements a naive `full-duplex tcp-port-forwarder:`

```
runProxy :: PortID -> AddrInfo -> IO ()
runProxy localPort@(PortNumber lpn) serverAddrInfo = do
  listener <- listenOn localPort

  forever $ do
    (sClient, clientAddr) <- accept listener

    let finalize sServer = do
            sClose sServer
            sClose sClient

    forkIO $ do
        tidToServer <- myThreadId
        bracket (connectToServer serverAddrInfo) finalize $ \sServer -> do
            -- execute one 'copySocket' thread for each data direction
            -- and make sure that if one direction dies, the other gets
            -- pulled down as well
            bracket (forkIO (copySocket sServer sClient
                             `finally` killThread tidToServer))
                    (killThread) $ \_ -> do
                copySocket sClient sServer -- "controlling" thread

 where
  -- |Copy data from source to dest until EOF occurs on source
  -- Copying may also be aborted due to exceptions
  copySocket :: Socket -> Socket -> IO ()
  copySocket src dst = go
   where
    go = do
        buf <- B.recv src 4096
        unless (B.null buf) $ do
            B.sendAll dst buf
            go

  -- |Create connection to given AddrInfo target and return socket
  connectToServer saddr = do
    sServer <- socket (addrFamily saddr) Stream defaultProtocol
    connect sServer (addrAddress saddr)
    return sServer
```

How do I transform the above skeleton into a `full-duplex ssl-wrapping tcp-forwarding proxy`? Where are the dangers W.R.T to concurrent/parallel execution (in the context of the above use-case) of the function calls provided by the HsOpenSSL API?

PS: I'm still struggling to fully comprehend how to make the code robust w.r.t. to exceptions and resource-leaks. So, albeit not being the primary focus of this question, if you notice something bad in the code above, please leave a comment.

Comment: I think this might be too broad a question for SO.

Comment: I'll get back to you on this :-)

Comment: the link to the doc is broken, here is the one who's working : http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HsOpenSSL/0.10.2/doc/html/OpenSSL-Session.html

Comment: I made something similar (`full-duplex ssl-rewrapping tcp-forwarding`), but it used `Network.TLS` (package `tls`) instead. And it was ugly. You can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/MLkQyxSn), if at all interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you need to replace `copySocket` with two different functions, one to handle data from the plain socket to SSL and the other from SSL to the plain socket:

```
  copyIn :: SSL.SSL -> Socket -> IO ()
  copyIn src dst = go
   where
    go = do
        buf <- SSL.read src 4096
        unless (B.null buf) $ do
            SB.sendAll dst buf
            go

  copyOut :: Socket -> SSL.SSL -> IO ()
  copyOut src dst = go
   where
    go = do
        buf <- SB.recv src 4096
        unless (B.null buf) $ do
            SSL.write dst buf
            go
```

Then you need to modify `connectToServer` so that it establishes an SSL connection

```
  -- |Create connection to given AddrInfo target and return socket
  connectToServer saddr = do
    sServer <- socket (addrFamily saddr) Stream defaultProtocol
    putStrLn "connecting"
    connect sServer (addrAddress saddr)
    putStrLn "establishing ssl context"
    ctx <- SSL.context
    putStrLn "setting ciphers"
    SSL.contextSetCiphers ctx "DEFAULT"
    putStrLn "setting verfication mode"
    SSL.contextSetVerificationMode ctx SSL.VerifyNone
    putStrLn "making ssl connection"
    sslServer <- SSL.connection ctx sServer
    putStrLn "doing handshake"
    SSL.connect sslServer
    putStrLn "connected"
    return sslServer
```

and change `finalize` to shut down the SSL session

```
let finalize sServer = do
        putStrLn "shutting down ssl"
        SSL.shutdown sServer SSL.Unidirectional
        putStrLn "closing server socket"
        maybe (return ()) sClose (SSL.sslSocket sServer)
        putStrLn "closing client socket"
        sClose sClient
```

Finally, don't forget to run your main stuff within `withOpenSSL` as in

```
main = withOpenSSL $ do
    let hints = defaultHints { addrSocketType = Stream, addrFamily = AF_INET }
    addrs <- getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just "localhost") (Just "22222")
    let addr = head addrs
    print addr
    runProxy (PortNumber 11111) addr
```

Comment: This already helps a lot; this provides a local-non-ssl-to-remote-ssl proxy corresponding to `stunnels` client-mode, could you also provide an example how to listen to a local ssl socket (e.g. to provide a local-ssl-to-remote-non-ssl proxy)?